# Windows kernel32 functions in Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, winapi, mono

I got this awesomely simple ini class that I downloaded from somewhere a while ago, but now that I'm using mono I'm running into the issue that it's importing stuff from kernel32

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key, string val, string filePath);
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
    int size, string filePath);
```

Which on mono (in linux) gives the error `DLLNotFoundException: kernel32`

Is there any way to get this to work with mono? Maybe embed the whole thing into the assembly at compile time (if that even makes sense at all, I wouldn't know). Or will I *have* to create/find an ini class that doesn't use WinAPI? (Nini springs to mind).

I'd really like it if WinAPI stuff could work with Mono, any thoughts?

Comment: Well, that's not going to work of course.  You need to stay away from these apis anyway, they are horribly expensive and don't support consistent string encoding.  Use xml.

Comment: Could it be that Mono is case-sensitive? Try importing Kernel32, with a capital K.

Comment: @HansPassant I will take your advice and move to xml for future projects, but I'd like to know if there is **any** way at all to get WinAPI functions in Mono regardless. I need to quick-fix some personal-use applications that really don't 'deserve' to be worked on long enough to get rid of the WinAPI dependency. So dirty, far-from-optimal fixes are welcome. If it's impossible then I'm just out of luck, but I'd like to know for sure ;)

Comment: Just to double-check, you're running Mono on Windows, right? Mono doesn't bring the Win32 API with it to other platforms (Wine does, but that might be a tricky integration). And if you're running on Windows, why are you using Mono instead of the MS CLR?

Comment: @Sblom No I am not using mono on windows, I'm running it on linux.. I probably should have mentioned that -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to rewrite the functionality of those functions in native .NET to use them on Mono/Linux (unless you can convince Mono and Wine to play nicely).

If the INI files are controlled, then you may get away with simple file/string manipulation, but then you may be better off moving to something a bit more cross platform anyway.

Answer (score 5):

[Mono supports C#'s P/Invoke](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries), which is what's required for running Win32 API functions. (As long as you're running Mono on Windows--the fact that it can't find `"kernel32"` causes me to suspect you're not.)

The site pinvoke.net collects the necessary DllImport signatures for most of the Win32 API.

[Here's what it has to say about GetPrivateProfileString.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.html)

This code worked for me using Mono 2.10.8 on Windows 7:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class MainClass
{
  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key, string val, string filePath);
  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
    int size, string filePath);

  static void Main()
  {
    StringBuilder asdf = new StringBuilder();
    GetPrivateProfileString("global","test","",asdf,100,@"c:\example\test.ini");
    Console.WriteLine(asdf.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to run it on linux I'm afraid. It does indeed work just fine in Windows using mono, but on linux it throws the kernel32 not found error. Which I totally understand, because linux obviously doesn't have WinAPI support. What I'm asking is, is there any way to port the functionality from some WinAPI libraries over to linux , or embed them directly into the assembly, so I don't have to code my way around them to get my programs to work on linux? My knowledge on WinAPI is quite bad so I wouldn't know how realistic that idea is at all.

Answer (score -3):

Change `[DllImport("kernel32")]` into `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]`

Everything will start working like supposed to.

Comment: Don't have time to test this atm but that would be pretty sweet.. did they create a wrapper (if that's the correct word for it, probably not) for it in a new version of mono?

Comment: The file extension should not be included in the DllImport .